# Postgresql - How to make NOT LIKE + SELECT statement, comparing two columns between tables

Tags: postgresql, select, wildcard, sql-like

Hit a bit of a brickwall here, I haven't found anything that seems to work.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM glsltransaction gls
        INNER JOIN glhistory h ON gls.sltrxid = h.schedxrefid
        INNER JOIN apvendor ap ON ap.vendorid = gls.acctid
        INNER JOIN glchartofaccounts coa USING (acctdeptid)
        WHERE h.description <> gls.description
            AND h.description not like || ap.name || '%'
            AND gls.description <> ''
```

This line here `AND h.description not like || ap.name || '%'` is what i'm having issues with.

I get the following error when trying to run that statement above:

'Error occurred in running query from editor : ERROR: operator does not exist: || text Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast. Position: 563'

I'm effectively wanting it to function like `a.column not like b.column%`

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What version of postgres?

Comment: What's the `||` doing between `like` and `ap.name`?

Comment: @OrangeDog I believe it's 11.5, but i'm not 100% positive.

Comment: @Noah That was a suggestion for something similar in another stackoverflow conversation, that I thought I'd try. It didn't work, unfortunately. It results in the error message referenced above.

Comment: Change it to `not like ap.name || '%'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that ended up working. Thanks for the help!